# Permutations in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, permutation

I'm trying to write a function that does the following:

- takes an array of integers as an argument (e.g. [1,2,3,4])
- creates an array of all the possible permutations of [1,2,3,4], with each permutation having a length of 4

the function below (I found it online) does this by taking a string as an argument, and returning all the permutations of that string

I could not figure out how to modify it to make it work with an array of integers, (I think this has something to do with how some of the methods work differently on strings than they do on integers, but I'm not sure...)

```
let permArr = [];
let usedChars = [];

function permute(input) {
    const chars = input.split("");
    for (let i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
        const ch = chars.splice(i, 1);
        usedChars.push(ch);
        if (chars.length === 0) {
            permArr[permArr.length] = usedChars.join("");
        }
        permute(chars.join(""));
        chars.splice(i, 0, ch);
        usedChars.pop();
    }
    return permArr
};
```

Note: I'm looking to make the function return arrays of *integers*, **not** an array of *strings*.

I really need the solution to be in JavaScript. I've already figured out how to do this in python

Comment: If you’re looking for a “concatenated” variant of permutations, i.e. from an array `[ 1, 2, 3, 4 ]` generating `[ "1234", "1243", "1324",`…`]`, see [Finding all permutations of array elements as concatenated strings](/q/66108781/4642212).

Answer (score 129, accepted):

If you notice, the code actually splits the chars into an array prior to do any permutation, so you simply remove the join and split operation

```js
var permArr = [],
  usedChars = [];

function permute(input) {
  var i, ch;
  for (i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
    ch = input.splice(i, 1)[0];
    usedChars.push(ch);
    if (input.length == 0) {
      permArr.push(usedChars.slice());
    }
    permute(input);
    input.splice(i, 0, ch);
    usedChars.pop();
  }
  return permArr
};


document.write(JSON.stringify(permute([5, 3, 7, 1])));
```

Comment: @SiGanteng. Something weird is happening to me trying to use your function. I keep it in a .js where I have all my "list manipulation function". If I use it with permute([1,2,3]), and later permute([4,5,6]), the output of the later still have the result, output from the first one. Any idea how to fix that ? Many thanks !

Comment: There's [a new question about this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21744120/trying-to-understand-recursion-within-for-loops-in-javascript).

Comment: Accessing globals in your function, bad form!

Answer (score 190):

Little late, but like to add a slightly more elegant version here.  Can be any array...

```
function permutator(inputArr) {
  var results = [];

  function permute(arr, memo) {
    var cur, memo = memo || [];

    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      cur = arr.splice(i, 1);
      if (arr.length === 0) {
        results.push(memo.concat(cur));
      }
      permute(arr.slice(), memo.concat(cur));
      arr.splice(i, 0, cur[0]);
    }

    return results;
  }

  return permute(inputArr);
}
```

Adding an ES6 (2015) version. Also does not mutate the original input array. Works in the console in Chrome...

```
const permutator = (inputArr) => {
  let result = [];

  const permute = (arr, m = []) => {
    if (arr.length === 0) {
      result.push(m)
    } else {
      for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        let curr = arr.slice();
        let next = curr.splice(i, 1);
        permute(curr.slice(), m.concat(next))
     }
   }
 }

 permute(inputArr)

 return result;
}
```

So...

```
permutator(['c','a','t']);
```

Yields...

```
[ [ 'c', 'a', 't' ],
  [ 'c', 't', 'a' ],
  [ 'a', 'c', 't' ],
  [ 'a', 't', 'c' ],
  [ 't', 'c', 'a' ],
  [ 't', 'a', 'c' ] ]
```

And...

```
permutator([1,2,3]);
```

Yields...

```
[ [ 1, 2, 3 ],
  [ 1, 3, 2 ],
  [ 2, 1, 3 ],
  [ 2, 3, 1 ],
  [ 3, 1, 2 ],
  [ 3, 2, 1 ] ]
```

Comment: If you have a factorial function handy (as is fairly likely considering you are dealing with permutations), you could speed it up by changing the outer scope initialization to  `var results = new Array(factorial(inputArr.length)), length=0`, then replace `results.push(…)` with `results[length++]=…`

Comment: What does line `var cur, memo = memo || [];` do ?

Comment: @user2965967 It declares cur and memo, and it initializes memo to be the value of memo, unless it is falsey (including undefined), in which case it will be an empty array. In other words, it's a less than ideal way to provide the function parameter with a default value.

Comment: This modifies the original array.

Comment: Added an ES6 (2015) version.  There is no mutation of the original array in the ES6 version.

Comment: @delimited, Can you please explain the ES6 approach? please reply with a link on any sharing code tools (e.g. plunker)  i will highly appreciate that. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you please provide Time Complexity of ES6 approach

Comment: is the `slice()` in `permute(curr.slice(), m.concat(next))` really necessary?

Comment: Wrote as a generator/iterator because I was hitting memory and speed problems on large sets.
```javascript
function* permutator(inputArr) {
  function* permute(arr, m) {
    if (arr.length === 0) {
      yield m;
    }
    else {
      for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        let curr = arr.slice();
        let next = curr.splice(i, 1);
        yield* permute(curr.slice(), m.concat(next));
      }
    }
  }
  yield* permute(inputArr, []);
}
```

Comment: how do we set the length of the permutation?

Answer (score 154):

The following very efficient algorithm uses [Heap's method](http://homepage.math.uiowa.edu/%7Egoodman/22m150.dir/2007/Permutation%20Generation%20Methods.pdf) to generate all permutations of N elements with runtime complexity in O(N!):

```js
function permute(permutation) {
  var length = permutation.length,
      result = [permutation.slice()],
      c = new Array(length).fill(0),
      i = 1, k, p;

  while (i < length) {
    if (c[i] < i) {
      k = i % 2 && c[i];
      p = permutation[i];
      permutation[i] = permutation[k];
      permutation[k] = p;
      ++c[i];
      i = 1;
      result.push(permutation.slice());
    } else {
      c[i] = 0;
      ++i;
    }
  }
  return result;
}

console.log(permute([1, 2, 3]));
```

The same algorithm implemented as a [generator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*) with space complexity in O(N):

```js
function* permute(permutation) {
  var length = permutation.length,
      c = Array(length).fill(0),
      i = 1, k, p;

  yield permutation.slice();
  while (i < length) {
    if (c[i] < i) {
      k = i % 2 && c[i];
      p = permutation[i];
      permutation[i] = permutation[k];
      permutation[k] = p;
      ++c[i];
      i = 1;
      yield permutation.slice();
    } else {
      c[i] = 0;
      ++i;
    }
  }
}

// Memory efficient iteration through permutations:
for (var permutation of permute([1, 2, 3])) console.log(permutation);

// Simple array conversion:
var permutations = [...permute([1, 2, 3])];
```

###Performance comparison
Feel free to add your implementation to the following [benchmark.js](https://benchmarkjs.com/) test suite:

```js
function permute_SiGanteng(input) {
  var permArr = [],
    usedChars = [];

  function permute(input) {
    var i, ch;
    for (i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
      ch = input.splice(i, 1)[0];
      usedChars.push(ch);
      if (input.length == 0) {
        permArr.push(usedChars.slice());
      }
      permute(input);
      input.splice(i, 0, ch);
      usedChars.pop();
    }
    return permArr
  }
  return permute(input);
}

function permute_delimited(inputArr) {
  var results = [];

  function permute(arr, memo) {
    var cur, memo = memo || [];
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      cur = arr.splice(i, 1);
      if (arr.length === 0) {
        results.push(memo.concat(cur));
      }
      permute(arr.slice(), memo.concat(cur));
      arr.splice(i, 0, cur[0]);
    }
    return results;
  }
  return permute(inputArr);
}

function permute_monkey(inputArray) {
  return inputArray.reduce(function permute(res, item, key, arr) {
    return res.concat(arr.length > 1 && arr.slice(0, key).concat(arr.slice(key + 1)).reduce(permute, []).map(function(perm) {
      return [item].concat(perm);
    }) || item);
  }, []);
}

function permute_Oriol(input) {
  var permArr = [],
    usedChars = [];
  return (function main() {
    for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
      var ch = input.splice(i, 1)[0];
      usedChars.push(ch);
      if (input.length == 0) {
        permArr.push(usedChars.slice());
      }
      main();
      input.splice(i, 0, ch);
      usedChars.pop();
    }
    return permArr;
  })();
}

function permute_MarkusT(input) {
  function permutate(array, callback) {
      function p(array, index, callback) {
          function swap(a, i1, i2) {
              var t = a[i1];
              a[i1] = a[i2];
              a[i2] = t;
          }
          if (index == array.length - 1) {
              callback(array);
              return 1;
          } else {
              var count = p(array, index + 1, callback);
              for (var i = index + 1; i < array.length; i++) {
                  swap(array, i, index);
                  count += p(array, index + 1, callback);
                  swap(array, i, index);
              }
              return count;
          }
      }
      if (!array || array.length == 0) {
          return 0;
      }
      return p(array, 0, callback);
  }
  var result = [];
  permutate(input, function(a) {
      result.push(a.slice(0));
  });
  return result;
}

function permute_le_m(permutation) {
  var length = permutation.length,
        result = [permutation.slice()],
      c = new Array(length).fill(0),
      i = 1, k, p;
  
  while (i < length) {
    if (c[i] < i) {
      k = i % 2 && c[i],
      p = permutation[i];
      permutation[i] = permutation[k];
      permutation[k] = p;
      ++c[i];
      i = 1;
      result.push(permutation.slice());
    } else {
      c[i] = 0;
      ++i;
    }
  }
  return result;
}

function permute_Urielzen(arr) {
    var finalArr = [];
    var iterator = function (arrayTaken, tree) {
        for (var i = 0; i < tree; i++) {
            var temp = arrayTaken.slice();
            temp.splice(tree - 1 - i, 0, temp.splice(tree - 1, 1)[0]);
            if (tree >= arr.length) {
                finalArr.push(temp);
            } else { iterator(temp, tree + 1); }
        }
    }
    iterator(arr, 1); return finalArr;
}

function permute_Taylor_Hakes(arr) {
  var permutations = [];
  if (arr.length === 1) {
    return [ arr ];
  }

  for (var i = 0; i <  arr.length; i++) { 
    var subPerms = permute_Taylor_Hakes(arr.slice(0, i).concat(arr.slice(i + 1)));
    for (var j = 0; j < subPerms.length; j++) {
      subPerms[j].unshift(arr[i]);
      permutations.push(subPerms[j]);
    }
  }
  return permutations;
}

// caub, variant duplicate safe
function permute_caub(xs) {
  if (!xs.length) return [[]];
  return xs.flatMap((x, i) => {
    return permute_caub(xs.filter((v, j) => i !== j)).map((vs) => [x, ...vs]);
  });
}

var Combinatorics = (function () {
    'use strict';
    var version = "0.5.2";
    /* combinatory arithmetics */
    var P = function(m, n) {
        var p = 1;
        while (n--) p *= m--;
        return p;
    };
    var C = function(m, n) {
        if (n > m) {
            return 0;
        }
        return P(m, n) / P(n, n);
    };
    var factorial = function(n) {
        return P(n, n);
    };
    var factoradic = function(n, d) {
        var f = 1;
        if (!d) {
            for (d = 1; f < n; f *= ++d);
            if (f > n) f /= d--;
        } else {
            f = factorial(d);
        }
        var result = [0];
        for (; d; f /= d--) {
            result[d] = Math.floor(n / f);
            n %= f;
        }
        return result;
    };
    /* common methods */
    var addProperties = function(dst, src) {
        Object.keys(src).forEach(function(p) {
            Object.defineProperty(dst, p, {
                value: src[p],
                configurable: p == 'next'
            });
        });
    };
    var hideProperty = function(o, p) {
        Object.defineProperty(o, p, {
            writable: true
        });
    };
    var toArray = function(f) {
        var e, result = [];
        this.init();
        while (e = this.next()) result.push(f ? f(e) : e);
        this.init();
        return result;
    };
    var common = {
        toArray: toArray,
        map: toArray,
        forEach: function(f) {
            var e;
            this.init();
            while (e = this.next()) f(e);
            this.init();
        },
        filter: function(f) {
            var e, result = [];
            this.init();
            while (e = this.next()) if (f(e)) result.push(e);
            this.init();
            return result;
        },
        lazyMap: function(f) {
            this._lazyMap = f;
            return this;
        },
        lazyFilter: function(f) {
            Object.defineProperty(this, 'next', {
                writable: true
            });
            if (typeof f !== 'function') {
                this.next = this._next;
            } else {
                if (typeof (this._next) !== 'function') {
                    this._next = this.next;
                }
                var _next = this._next.bind(this);
                this.next = (function() {
                    var e;
                    while (e = _next()) {
                        if (f(e))
                            return e;
                    }
                    return e;
                }).bind(this);
            }
            Object.defineProperty(this, 'next', {
                writable: false
            });
            return this;
        }

    };
    /* power set */
    var power = function(ary, fun) {
        var size = 1 << ary.length,
            sizeOf = function() {
                return size;
            },
            that = Object.create(ary.slice(), {
                length: {
                    get: sizeOf
                }
            });
        hideProperty(that, 'index');
        addProperties(that, {
            valueOf: sizeOf,
            init: function() {
                that.index = 0;
            },
            nth: function(n) {
                if (n >= size) return;
                var i = 0,
                    result = [];
                for (; n; n >>>= 1, i++) if (n & 1) result.push(this[i]);
                return (typeof (that._lazyMap) === 'function')?that._lazyMap(result):result;
            },
            next: function() {
                return this.nth(this.index++);
            }
        });
        addProperties(that, common);
        that.init();
        return (typeof (fun) === 'function') ? that.map(fun) : that;
    };
    /* combination */
    var nextIndex = function(n) {
        var smallest = n & -n,
            ripple = n + smallest,
            new_smallest = ripple & -ripple,
            ones = ((new_smallest / smallest) >> 1) - 1;
        return ripple | ones;
    };
    var combination = function(ary, nelem, fun) {
        if (!nelem) nelem = ary.length;
        if (nelem < 1) throw new RangeError;
        if (nelem > ary.length) throw new RangeError;
        var first = (1 << nelem) - 1,
            size = C(ary.length, nelem),
            maxIndex = 1 << ary.length,
            sizeOf = function() {
                return size;
            },
            that = Object.create(ary.slice(), {
                length: {
                    get: sizeOf
                }
            });
        hideProperty(that, 'index');
        addProperties(that, {
            valueOf: sizeOf,
            init: function() {
                this.index = first;
            },
            next: function() {
                if (this.index >= maxIndex) return;
                var i = 0,
                    n = this.index,
                    result = [];
                for (; n; n >>>= 1, i++) {
                    if (n & 1) result[result.length] = this[i];
                }

                this.index = nextIndex(this.index);
                return (typeof (that._lazyMap) === 'function')?that._lazyMap(result):result;
            }
        });
        addProperties(that, common);
        that.init();
        return (typeof (fun) === 'function') ? that.map(fun) : that;
    };
    /* permutation */
    var _permutation = function(ary) {
        var that = ary.slice(),
            size = factorial(that.length);
        that.index = 0;
        that.next = function() {
            if (this.index >= size) return;
            var copy = this.slice(),
                digits = factoradic(this.index, this.length),
                result = [],
                i = this.length - 1;
            for (; i >= 0; --i) result.push(copy.splice(digits[i], 1)[0]);
            this.index++;
            return (typeof (that._lazyMap) === 'function')?that._lazyMap(result):result;
        };
        return that;
    };
    // which is really a permutation of combination
    var permutation = function(ary, nelem, fun) {
        if (!nelem) nelem = ary.length;
        if (nelem < 1) throw new RangeError;
        if (nelem > ary.length) throw new RangeError;
        var size = P(ary.length, nelem),
            sizeOf = function() {
                return size;
            },
            that = Object.create(ary.slice(), {
                length: {
                    get: sizeOf
                }
            });
        hideProperty(that, 'cmb');
        hideProperty(that, 'per');
        addProperties(that, {
            valueOf: function() {
                return size;
            },
            init: function() {
                this.cmb = combination(ary, nelem);
                this.per = _permutation(this.cmb.next());
            },
            next: function() {
                var result = this.per.next();
                if (!result) {
                    var cmb = this.cmb.next();
                    if (!cmb) return;
                    this.per = _permutation(cmb);
                    return this.next();
                }
                return (typeof (that._lazyMap) === 'function')?that._lazyMap(result):result;
            }
        });
        addProperties(that, common);
        that.init();
        return (typeof (fun) === 'function') ? that.map(fun) : that;
    };

    /* export */
    var Combinatorics = Object.create(null);
    addProperties(Combinatorics, {
        C: C,
        P: P,
        factorial: factorial,
        factoradic: factoradic,
        permutation: permutation,
    });
    return Combinatorics;
})();

function permute_Technicalbloke(inputArray) {
  if (inputArray.length === 1) return inputArray;
  return inputArray.reduce( function(accumulator,_,index){
    permute_Technicalbloke([...inputArray.slice(0,index),...inputArray.slice(index+1)])
    .map(value=>accumulator.push([inputArray[index],value]));
    return accumulator;
  },[]);
}

var suite = new Benchmark.Suite;
var input = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4];

suite.add('permute_SiGanteng', function() {
    permute_SiGanteng(input);
  })
  .add('permute_delimited', function() {
    permute_delimited(input);
  })
  .add('permute_monkey', function() {
    permute_monkey(input);
  })
  .add('permute_Oriol', function() {
    permute_Oriol(input);
  })
  .add('permute_MarkusT', function() {
    permute_MarkusT(input);
  })
  .add('permute_le_m', function() {
    permute_le_m(input);
  })
  .add('permute_Urielzen', function() {
    permute_Urielzen(input);
  })
  .add('permute_Taylor_Hakes', function() {
    permute_Taylor_Hakes(input);
  })
  .add('permute_Combinatorics', function() {
    Combinatorics.permutation(input).toArray();
  })
  .add('permute_Technicalbloke', function() {
    permute_Technicalbloke(input);
  })
  .add('permute_caub', function() {
    permute_caub(input);
  })
  .on('cycle', function(event) {
    console.log(String(event.target));
  })
  .on('complete', function() {
    console.log('Fastest is ' + this.filter('fastest').map('name'));
  })
  .run({async: true});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/platform/1.3.4/platform.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/benchmark/2.1.4/benchmark.min.js"></script>
```

Run-time results for Chrome 48:

- 99.152ms **This algorithm**
- 153.115ms [MarkusT](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11629015/1647737)
- 401.255ms [js-combinatorics](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30013816/1647737)
- 497.037ms [Urielzen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24622772/1647737)
- 925.669ms [Oriol](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11509565/1647737)
- 1026.571ms [SiGanteng](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9960925/1647737)
- 2529.841ms [delimited](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20871714/1647737)
- 3992.622ms [monkey](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22063440/1647737)
- 4514.665ms [Oriol](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32551801/1647737)

Comment: How can this code be changed to deliver results for a fixed n = 2? 
For example, suppose we have a set of three letters: A, B, and C. We might ask how many ways we can arrange 2 letters from that set. Each possible arrangement would be an example of a permutation. The complete list of possible permutations would be: AB, AC, BA, BC, CA, and CB.

Comment: @a4xrbj1 See e.g. the code sample in this question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37892738/generate-subsets-of-length-n - or are you specifically asking about modifying this (Heap's) method?

Comment: @le_m yes, specifically using this (Heap's) method as it's so fast

Comment: @a4xrbj1 I would compute all combinations of fixed length n (e.g. AB, AC, BC for n = 2) using a similar strategy to the link given above (see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/127704/algorithm-to-return-all-combinations-of-k-elements-from-n) and then for each combination compute all of its permutations using Heap's method. Special cases such as n = 2 can of course be optimized.

Comment: This answer is so much superior to the the accepted answer! Especially the generator version, if you want permutations of anything more than a tiny array, this is the way to go.

Comment: The generator version doesn't work properly, you should do `yield permutation.slice()` if you don't slice you only get the last permutation calculated.

Comment: @Beldar You are right, especially regarding the array conversion. For the simple iteration however, mutating the same permutation might be beneficial in certain cases. However, this code can't satisfy all needs, will update to slicing then. Thanks for pointing it out

Comment: Tried to add my answer to the benchmark but it's not calculating. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 58):

```
var inputArray = [1, 2, 3];

var result = inputArray.reduce(function permute(res, item, key, arr) {
    return res.concat(arr.length > 1 && arr.slice(0, key)
        .concat(arr.slice(key + 1))
        .reduce(permute, [])
        .map(function (perm) {
            return [item].concat(perm);
        }) || item);
}, []);


alert(JSON.stringify(result));
```

Comment: Wow, despite its terseness and lack of docs, I think this is the most elegant answer.  
  
My explanation of this algorithm is:  
  
    For every item in the array (reduce), select all other items, permute them (recursively), and concat to this item.

Comment: Tried this solution here: http://www.codewars.com/kata/reviews/5254ca2719453dcc0b000280/groups/55fbc3a2bbef4feb3b000114 I've unwrapped the original golf code into a readable one, but it's essentially the same. The problem with it is that it produces duplicates, and I had to do an additional `.filter(uniq)` on the result.

Comment: is there a lisp parallel to the concept `[1,2,3].length == 3 && "foo" || "bar"`or `[1,2].length == 3 && "foo" || "bar"` oh my! there is! `(or (and (= 3 2) (print "hello!")) (print "goodbye"))`

Comment: @lolmaus-AndreyMikhaylov how to remove duplicacy please Update the answer if you can

Comment: @PardeepJain I gave a link to my solution above.

Comment: How can it be elegant if it's not even readable. It's an easy fix, I suggest an edit.

Answer (score 23):

Some version inspired from Haskell:

```
perms [] = [[]]
perms xs = [ x:ps | x <- xs , ps <- perms ( xs\\[x] ) ]
```

```js
function perms(xs) {
  if (!xs.length) return [[]];
  return xs.flatMap(x => {
    // get permutations of xs without x, then prepend x to each
    return perms(xs.filter(v => v!==x)).map(vs => [x, ...vs]);
  });
  // or this duplicate-safe way, suggested by @M.Charbonnier in the comments
  // return xs.flatMap((x, i) => {
  //   return perms(xs.filter((v, j) => i!==j)).map(vs => [x, ...vs]);
  // });
  // or @user3658510's variant
  // return xs.flatMap((x, i) => {
  //   return perms([...xs.slice(0,i),...xs.slice(i+1)]).map(vs => [x,...vs]);
  // });
}
document.write(JSON.stringify(perms([1,2,3])));
```

Comment: Nice. Here are some of my though that may help someone latter. At this time, for each recursion, the array has to be iterated in all his elements when filtered by x (the first element). That could be avoided with something like: `perms([...xs.slice(0, i), ...xs.slice(i + 1)]).map(vs => [x, ...vs])`. 
I don't really know if recreating the array with the spread as i suggest is more performant than the filter, so i searched the net and found this test that suggest that it might be worse https://www.measurethat.net/Benchmarks/ShowResult/213878. So probably a bad idea with a very large data set :(

Comment: It is a great and elegant solution, very short, but not a good performance. I added it to @le_m benchmark (code Snipet) and it ha one of the lowest. `7,293 ops/sec` vs the best one: `378,289 ops/sec`

Answer (score 21):

I have improved [SiGanteng](https://stackoverflow.com/users/135448/siganteng)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9960925/1529630).

Now it is possible to call `permute` more than once, because `permArr` and `usedChars` are cleared each time.

```js
function permute(input) {
    var permArr = [],
        usedChars = [];
    return (function main() {
        for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
            var ch = input.splice(i, 1)[0];
            usedChars.push(ch);
            if (input.length == 0) {
                permArr.push(usedChars.slice());
            }
            main();
            input.splice(i, 0, ch);
            usedChars.pop();
        }
        return permArr;
    })();
}
```

```js
function permute(input) {
  var permArr = [],
      usedChars = [];
  return (function main() {
    for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
      var ch = input.splice(i, 1)[0];
      usedChars.push(ch);
      if (input.length == 0) {
        permArr.push(usedChars.slice());
      }
      main();
      input.splice(i, 0, ch);
      usedChars.pop();
    }
    return permArr;
  })();
}
document.write(JSON.stringify(permute([5, 3, 7, 1])));
```

Answer (score 16):

Most answers to this question use expensive operations like continuous insertions and deletions of items in an array, or copying arrays reiteratively.

Instead, this is the typical backtracking solution:

```js
function permute(arr) {
  var results = [],
      l = arr.length,
      used = Array(l), // Array of bools. Keeps track of used items
      data = Array(l); // Stores items of the current permutation
  (function backtracking(pos) {
    if(pos == l) return results.push(data.slice());
    for(var i=0; i<l; ++i) if(!used[i]) { // Iterate unused items
      used[i] = true;      // Mark item as used
      data[pos] = arr[i];  // Assign item at the current position
      backtracking(pos+1); // Recursive call
      used[i] = false;     // Mark item as not used
    }
  })(0);
  return results;
}
```

```js
permute([1,2,3,4]); // [  [1,2,3,4], [1,2,4,3], /* ... , */ [4,3,2,1]  ]
```

Since the results array will be huge, it might be a good idea to iterate the results one by one instead of allocating all the data simultaneously. In ES6, this can be done with generators:

```js
function permute(arr) {
  var l = arr.length,
      used = Array(l),
      data = Array(l);
  return function* backtracking(pos) {
    if(pos == l) yield data.slice();
    else for(var i=0; i<l; ++i) if(!used[i]) {
      used[i] = true;
      data[pos] = arr[i];
      yield* backtracking(pos+1);
      used[i] = false;
    }
  }(0);
}
```

```js
var p = permute([1,2,3,4]);
p.next(); // {value: [1,2,3,4], done: false}
p.next(); // {value: [1,2,4,3], done: false}
// ...
p.next(); // {value: [4,3,2,1], done: false}
p.next(); // {value: undefined, done: true}
```

Answer (score 12):

Here's a very concise and recursive solution that allows you to input the size of the output permutations similar to the statistical operator nPr. "5 permutation 3". This allows you to get all possible permutations with a specific size.

```
function generatePermutations(list, size=list.length) {
    if (size > list.length) return [];
    else if (size == 1) return list.map(d=>[d]); 
    return list.flatMap(d => generatePermutations(list.filter(a => a !== d), size - 1).map(item => [d, ...item]));
}
```

`generatePermutations([1,2,3])`

```
[[1, 2, 3],[1, 3, 2], [2, 1, 3], [2, 3, 1], [3, 1, 2], [3, 2, 1]]
```

`generatePermutations([1,2,3],2)`

```
[[1, 2], [1, 3], [2, 1], [2, 3], [3, 1], [3, 2]]
```

Answer (score 11):

The following function permutates an array of any type and calls a specified callback function on each permutation found:

```
/*
  Permutate the elements in the specified array by swapping them
  in-place and calling the specified callback function on the array
  for each permutation.

  Return the number of permutations.

  If array is undefined, null or empty, return 0.

  NOTE: when permutation succeeds, the array should be in the original state
  on exit!
*/
  function permutate(array, callback) {
    // Do the actual permuation work on array[], starting at index
    function p(array, index, callback) {
      // Swap elements i1 and i2 in array a[]
      function swap(a, i1, i2) {
        var t = a[i1];
        a[i1] = a[i2];
        a[i2] = t;
      }

      if (index == array.length - 1) {
        callback(array);
        return 1;
      } else {
        var count = p(array, index + 1, callback);
        for (var i = index + 1; i < array.length; i++) {
          swap(array, i, index);
          count += p(array, index + 1, callback);
          swap(array, i, index);
        }
        return count;
      }
    }

    if (!array || array.length == 0) {
      return 0;
    }
    return p(array, 0, callback);
  }
```

If you call it like this:

```
  // Empty array to hold results
  var result = [];
  // Permutate [1, 2, 3], pushing every permutation onto result[]
  permutate([1, 2, 3], function (a) {
    // Create a copy of a[] and add that to result[]
    result.push(a.slice(0));
  });
  // Show result[]
  document.write(result);
```

I think it will do exactly what you need - fill an array called `result` with the permutations of the array [1, 2, 3]. The result is:

```
[[1,2,3],[1,3,2],[2,1,3],[2,3,1],[3,2,1],[3,1,2]]
```

Slightly clearer code on JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MgmMg/6/

Answer (score 11):

## Here's a cool solution

```js
const rotations = ([l, ...ls], right=[]) =>
  l !== void 0 ? [[l, ...ls, ...right], ...rotations(ls, [...right, l])] : []

const permutations = ([x, ...xs]) =>
  x !== void 0 ? permutations(xs).flatMap((p) => rotations([x, ...p])) : [[]]
  
console.log(permutations("cat"))
```

Answer (score 11):

Fastest, most (resorces) effective and most elegant version nowadays (2020)

```js
function getArrayMutations (arr, perms = [], len = arr.length) {
  if (len === 1) perms.push(arr.slice(0))

  for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    getArrayMutations(arr, perms, len - 1)

    len % 2 // parity dependent adjacent elements swap
      ? [arr[0], arr[len - 1]] = [arr[len - 1], arr[0]]
      : [arr[i], arr[len - 1]] = [arr[len - 1], arr[i]]
  }

  return perms
}

const arrayToMutate = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

const startTime = performance.now()
const arrayOfMutations = getArrayMutations(arrayToMutate)
const stopTime = performance.now()
const duration = (stopTime - startTime) / 1000

console.log(`${arrayOfMutations.length.toLocaleString('en-US')} permutations found in ${duration.toLocaleString('en-US')}s`)
```

Comment: Hi, do you mind explaining what `len % 2 // parity dependent adjacent elements swap` means and why is it used?

Comment: My code uses the "Heap's algorithm" to generate the array permutations. So, if you want to know how my code works under the hood, read this explanation of the Heap's algorithm: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap%27s_algorithm

Comment: Did you try to print the result? how to control the maximum if the array elements over 10?

Comment: problem is it keeps the rest of array even if you pass ```len```. it can be optimized I guess.

Answer (score 6):

Answer without the need for a exterior array or additional function

```
function permutator (arr) {
  var permutations = [];
  if (arr.length === 1) {
    return [ arr ];
  }

  for (var i = 0; i <  arr.length; i++) { 
    var subPerms = permutator(arr.slice(0, i).concat(arr.slice(i + 1)));
    for (var j = 0; j < subPerms.length; j++) {
      subPerms[j].unshift(arr[i]);
      permutations.push(subPerms[j]);
    }
  }
  return permutations;
}
```

Comment: can you make a COmbination out of it ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53555563/how-to-implement-combinations-in-angular-2

Answer (score 6):

This is an interesting task and and here is my contribution. It's very simple and fast. If interested please bear with me and read on.

If you would like to this job fast, you definitely have to get yourself into dynamical programming. Which means you should forget about recursive approaches. That's for sure...

OK [le_m's code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37580979/4543207) which uses the Heap's method seems to be the fastest so far. Well i haven't got a name for my algorithm, i don't know  if it's already been implemented or not but it's very simple and fast. As with all dynamical programming approaches we will start with the simplest problem and go for the final result.

Assuming that we have an array of `a = [1,2,3]` we will start with

```
r = [[1]]; // result
t = [];    // interim result
```

Then follow these three steps;

1. For each item of our `r` (result) array we will add the next item of the input array.
2. We will rotate each item it's length many times and will store each instance at the interim result array `t`. (well except for the first one not to waste time with 0 rotation)
3. Once we finish with all items of `r` the interim array `t` should hold the next level of results so we make `r = t; t = [];` and carry on up until the length of the input array `a`.

So the following are our steps;

```
r array   | push next item to |  get length many rotations
          |  each sub array   |       of each subarray
-----------------------------------------------------------
[[1]]     |     [[1,2]]       |     [[1,2],[2,1]]
----------|-------------------|----------------------------
[[1,2],   |     [[1,2,3],     |     [[1,2,3],[2,3,1],[3,1,2],
 [2,1]]   |      [2,1,3]]     |      [2,1,3],[1,3,2],[3,2,1]]
----------|-------------------|----------------------------
previous t|                   |
-----------------------------------------------------------
```

So here is the code

```js
function perm(a){
  var r = [[a[0]]],
      t = [],
      s = [];
  if (a.length <= 1) return a;
  for (var i = 1, la = a.length; i < la; i++){
    for (var j = 0, lr = r.length; j < lr; j++){
      r[j].push(a[i]);
      t.push(r[j]);
      for(var k = 1, lrj = r[j].length; k < lrj; k++){
        for (var l = 0; l < lrj; l++) s[l] = r[j][(k+l)%lrj];
        t[t.length] = s;
        s = [];
      }
    }
    r = t;
    t = [];
  }
  return r;
}

var arr = [0,1,2,4,5];
console.log("The length of the permutation is:",perm(arr).length);
console.time("Permutation test");
for (var z = 0; z < 2000; z++) perm(arr);
console.timeEnd("Permutation test");
```

In multiple test i have seen it resolving the 120 permutations of [0,1,2,3,4] for 2000 times in 25~35ms.

Comment: It seems to run really fast, sometimes faster, sometimes slower than the Heap method on FF/Ubuntu for different length / warm-up iterations etc. Would need a jsperf to see results for different engines.

Comment: @le_m Thanks. Yes it changes depending on the JS Engine, OS and the CPU type. We might give a try on [JSBen](http://jsben.ch/#/index)

Comment: @le_m OK i have done [some test @JSBen](http://jsben.ch/#/layQf) On Ubuntu & AMD CPU: With Chrome `rotatePerm` (the above one) is consistenly 1.2 faster. With FF there is no consistency. After multiple tests sometimes `heapPerm` is 2 times faster some times `rotatePerm` is 1.1 times faster. With other web-kit browsers such as Opera or Epiphany `rotatePerm` consistently turns out to be 1.1 times faster. However with Edge `heapPerm` is consistently 1.2 times faster every single time.

Comment: Nice! It seems that - at least on FF/Ubuntu - the performance of the heap method mainly depends on the performance of array copying. I modified your benchmark to compare slicing vs. pushing: http://jsben.ch/#/x7mYh - on FF and for small input arrays, pushing seems much faster

Comment: @le_m Right in my experience `.push` is very efficient too. Now that you have modified `heapPerm` with push, it turns out to be like 1.2 times faster on Chrome as well. I believe i can boost my algorithm's performance further by manually caching a permutation map of a 3 item array and taking over from there for larger inputs. Actually i had the idea to generate a dynamic cache map but couldn't wrap my head around that. If, could be done it will be super fast.

Comment: Would be great if the heap method could be beaten performance-wise. By the way, your method generates the same output as Langdon's algorithm (page 16) from the same 1977 paper I used as a reference for Heap's method: http://homepage.math.uiowa.edu/~goodman/22m150.dir/2007/Permutation%20Generation%20Methods.pdf

Comment: @le_m I have just checked and it seems to be the same thing. I seem to do rotation like he implemented. Just with 40 years delay. As i have mentioned in my answer it's in fact a very simple method. Mentioned to be the choice only when fast rotation is available. Currently i am in to Haskell and it has a built in method to make a list (lets say array) [cycle](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:cycle) indefinitely (lazy evaluation makes an infinite repetition  no problem) and this might come handy. Yet, Haskell already has a standard `permutations` function :)

Comment: Can a combination be made out of it 
 - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53555563/how-to-implement-combinations-in-angular-2

Comment: @Techdive Combinations or subsequences or subarrays whatever people call it... is a different animal so requires a different algorithm. [Here you may find my approach which i believe to be very efficient](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39526032/4543207) especially the binary version one.

Answer (score 5):

Here is another "more recursive" solution.

```js
function perms(input) {
  var data = input.slice();
  var permutations = [];
  var n = data.length;

  if (n === 0) {
    return [
      []
    ];
  } else {
    var first = data.shift();
    var words = perms(data);
    words.forEach(function(word) {
      for (var i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        var tmp = word.slice();
        tmp.splice(i, 0, first)
        permutations.push(tmp);
      }
    });
  }

  return permutations;
}

var str = 'ABC';
var chars = str.split('');
var result = perms(chars).map(function(p) {
  return p.join('');
});

console.log(result);

var output = window.document.getElementById('output');
output.innerHTML = result;
```

```html
<div id="output"></div>
```

Output:

```
[ 'ABC', 'BAC', 'BCA', 'ACB', 'CAB', 'CBA' ]
```

Comment: can you make a combination for it ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53555563/how-to-implement-combinations-in-angular-2

Answer (score 4):

My first contribution to the site. Also, according to the tests that I have done, this code runs faster than all the other methods mentioned here before this date, of course it is minimal if there are few values, but the time increases exponentially when adding too many.

```js
var result = permutations([1,2,3,4]);

var output = window.document.getElementById('output');
output.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(result);

function permutations(arr) {
    var finalArr = [];
    function iterator(arrayTaken, tree) {
        var temp;
        for (var i = 0; i < tree; i++) {
            temp = arrayTaken.slice();
            temp.splice(tree - 1 - i, 0, temp.splice(tree - 1, 1)[0]);
            if (tree >= arr.length) {
                finalArr.push(temp);
            } else {
                iterator(temp, tree + 1);
            }
        }
    }
    iterator(arr, 1);
    return finalArr;
};
```

```html
<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: I added a performance comparison http://stackoverflow.com/a/37580979/1647737 - feel free to update.

Comment: amazing solution to this issue!!! took me a while to understand this code and it's beautifully clean man. good job!!

Answer (score 3):

Most of the other answers do not utilize the new javascript generator functions which is a perfect solution to this type of problem.  You probably only need one permutation at time in memory.  Also, I prefer to generate a permutation of a range of indices as this allows me to index each permutation and jump straight to any particular permutation as well as be used to permutate any other collection.

```js
// ES6 generator version of python itertools [permutations and combinations]
const range = function*(l) { for (let i = 0; i < l; i+=1) yield i; }
const isEmpty = arr => arr.length === 0;

const permutations = function*(a) {
    const r = arguments[1] || [];
    if (isEmpty(a)) yield r;
    for (let i of range(a.length)) {
        const aa = [...a];
        const rr = [...r, ...aa.splice(i, 1)];
        yield* permutations(aa, rr);
    }
}
console.log('permutations of ABC');
console.log(JSON.stringify([...permutations([...'ABC'])]));

const combinations = function*(a, count) {
    const r = arguments[2] || [];
    if (count) {
        count = count - 1;
        for (let i of range(a.length - count)) {
            const aa = a.slice(i);
            const rr = [...r, ...aa.splice(0, 1)];
            yield* combinations(aa, count, rr);
        }
    } else {
        yield r;
    }
}
console.log('combinations of 2 of ABC');
console.log(JSON.stringify([...combinations([...'ABC'], 2)]));



const permutator = function() {
    const range = function*(args) {
        let {begin = 0, count} = args;
        for (let i = begin; count; count--, i+=1) {
            yield i;
        }
    }
    const factorial = fact => fact ? fact * factorial(fact - 1) : 1;

    return {
        perm: function(n, permutationId) {
            const indexCount = factorial(n);
            permutationId = ((permutationId%indexCount)+indexCount)%indexCount;

            let permutation = [0];
            for (const choiceCount of range({begin: 2, count: n-1})) {
                const choice = permutationId % choiceCount;
                const lastIndex = permutation.length;

                permutation.push(choice);
                permutation = permutation.map((cv, i, orig) => 
                    (cv < choice || i == lastIndex) ? cv : cv + 1
                );

                permutationId = Math.floor(permutationId / choiceCount);
            }
            return permutation.reverse();
        },
        perms: function*(n) {
            for (let i of range({count: factorial(n)})) {
                yield this.perm(n, i);
            }
        }
    };
}();

console.log('indexing type permutator');
let i = 0;
for (let elem of permutator.perms(3)) {
  console.log(`${i}: ${elem}`);
  i+=1;
}
console.log();
console.log(`3: ${permutator.perm(3,3)}`);
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's one I made...

```
const permute = (ar) =>
  ar.length === 1 ? ar : ar.reduce( (ac,_,i) =>
    {permute([...ar.slice(0,i),...ar.slice(i+1)]).map(v=>ac.push([].concat(ar[i],v))); return ac;},[]);
```

And here it is again but written less tersely!...

```
function permute(inputArray) {
  if (inputArray.length === 1) return inputArray;
  return inputArray.reduce( function(accumulator,_,index){
    permute([...inputArray.slice(0,index),...inputArray.slice(index+1)])
      .map(value=>accumulator.push([].concat(inputArray[index],value)));
    return accumulator;
  },[]);
}
```

How it works: If the array is longer than one element it steps through each element and concatenates it with a recursive call to itself with the remaining elements as it's argument. It doesn't mutate the original array.

Answer (score 3):

Functional answer using flatMap:

```
const getPermutationsFor = (arr, permutation = []) =>
  arr.length === 0
    ? [permutation]
    : arr.flatMap((item, i, arr) =>
        getPermutationsFor(
          arr.filter((_,j) => j !== i),
          [...permutation, item]
        )
      );
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
"use strict";
function getPermutations(arrP) {
    var results = [];
    var arr = arrP;
    arr.unshift(null);
    var length = arr.length;

    while (arr[0] === null) {

        results.push(arr.slice(1).join(''));

        let less = null;
        let lessIndex = null;

        for (let i = length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
            if(arr[i - 1] < arr[i]){
                less = arr[i - 1];
                lessIndex = i - 1;
                break;
            }
        }

        for (let i = length - 1; i > lessIndex; i--) {
            if(arr[i] > less){
                arr[lessIndex] = arr[i];
                arr[i] = less;
                break;
            }
        }

        for(let i = lessIndex + 1; i<length; i++){
           for(let j = i + 1; j < length; j++){
               if(arr[i] > arr[j] ){
                   arr[i] = arr[i] + arr[j];
                   arr[j] = arr[i] - arr[j];
                   arr[i] = arr[i] - arr[j];
               }
           }
        }
    }

    return results;
}

var res = getPermutations([1,2,3,4,5]);
var out = document.getElementById('myTxtArr');
res.forEach(function(i){ out.value+=i+', '});
```

```css
textarea{
   height:500px;
  width:500px;
}
```

```html
<textarea id='myTxtArr'></textarea>
```

Outputs lexicographically ordered permutations. Works only with numbers. In other case, you have to change the swap method on line 34.

Answer (score 2):

```
   function perm(xs) {
       return xs.length === 0 ? [[]] : perm(xs.slice(1)).reduce(function (acc, ys) {
        for (var i = 0; i < xs.length; i++) {
          acc.push([].concat(ys.slice(0, i), xs[0], ys.slice(i)));
        }
        return acc;
      }, []);
    }
```

Test it with:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(perm([1, 2, 3,4])));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
"use strict";

function perm(arr) {
    if(arr.length<2) return [arr];
    var res = [];
    arr.forEach(function(x, i) {
        perm(arr.slice(0,i).concat(arr.slice(i+1))).forEach(function(a) {
            res.push([x].concat(a));
        });
    });
    return res;
}

console.log(perm([1,2,3,4]));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
perm = x => x[0] ?  x.reduce((a, n) => (perm(x.filter(m => m!=n)).forEach(y => a.push([n,...y])), a), []): [[]]
```

Comment: Can you add an explanation please.

Comment: While this answer _may_ solve the question, it contains no explanation of how or why it does so.

Answer (score 2):

Quite late. Still just in case if this helps anyone.

```js
function permute(arr) {
  if (arr.length == 1) return arr

  let res = arr.map((d, i) => permute([...arr.slice(0, i),...arr.slice(i + 1)])
                              .map(v => [d,v].join(''))).flat()

  return res
}

console.log(permute([1,2,3,4]))
```

Answer (score 1):

Similar in spirit to the Haskell-style solution by @crl, but working with `reduce`:

```
function permutations( base ) {
  if (base.length == 0) return [[]]
  return permutations( base.slice(1) ).reduce( function(acc,perm) {
    return acc.concat( base.map( function(e,pos) {
      var new_perm = perm.slice()
      new_perm.splice(pos,0,base[0])
      return new_perm
    }))
  },[])    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a very nice use-case for map/reduce:

```
function permutations(arr) {
    return (arr.length === 1) ? arr :
    arr.reduce((acc, cv, index) => {
        let remaining = [...arr];
        remaining.splice(index, 1);
        return acc.concat(permutations(remaining).map(a => [].concat(cv,a)));
    }, []);
}
```

- First, we handle the base case and simply return the array if there is only on item in it
- In all other cases

  - we create an empty array
  - loop over the input-array
  - and add an array of the current value and all permutations of the remaining array `[].concat(cv,a)`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a minimal ES6 version. The flatten and without functions can be pulled from Lodash.

```
const flatten = xs =>
    xs.reduce((cum, next) => [...cum, ...next], []);

const without = (xs, x) =>
    xs.filter(y => y !== x);

const permutations = xs =>
    flatten(xs.map(x =>
        xs.length < 2
            ? [xs]
            : permutations(without(xs, x)).map(perm => [x, ...perm])
    ));
```

Result:

```
permutations([1,2,3])
// [[1, 2, 3], [1, 3, 2], [2, 1, 3], [2, 3, 1], [3, 1, 2], [3, 2, 1]]
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const permutations = array => {
  let permut = [];
  helperFunction(0, array, permut);
  return permut;
};

const helperFunction = (i, array, permut) => {
  if (i === array.length - 1) {
    permut.push(array.slice());
  } else {
    for (let j = i; j < array.length; j++) {
      swapElements(i, j, array);
      helperFunction(i + 1, array, permut);
      swapElements(i, j, array);
    }
  }
};

function swapElements(a, b, array) {
  let temp = array[a];
  array[a] = array[b];
  array[b] = temp;
}

console.log(permutations([1, 2, 3]));
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a crack at making a version of this that attempts to be concise yet readable, and purely functional programming.

```
function stringPermutations ([...input]) {
  if (input.length === 1) return input;

  return input
    .map((thisChar, index) => {
      const remainingChars = [...input.slice(0, index), ...input.slice(index + 1)];
      return stringPermutations(remainingChars)
        .map(remainder => thisChar + remainder);
    })
    .reduce((acc, cur) => [...acc, ...cur]);
}
```

Note that the argument formatting turns an input string into an array. Not sure if that's a bit too *magical*.. Not sure I've seen it in the wild. For real readability I'd probably instead do `input = [...input]` for the first line of the function.

Answer (score 1):

This is an implementation of Heap's algorithm (similar to @le_m's), except it's recursive.

```
function permute_kingzee(arr,n=arr.length,out=[]) {
    if(n == 1) {
        return out.push(arr.slice());
    } else {
        for(let i=0; i<n; i++) {
            permute_kingzee(arr,n-1, out);
            let j = ( n % 2 == 0 ) ? i : 0;
            let t = arr[n-1];
            arr[n-1] = arr[j];
            arr[j] = t;
        }
        return out;
    }
}
```

It looks like it's quite faster too : https://jsfiddle.net/3brqzaLe/

Answer (score 1):

This is just little bit more succinct version of delimited's

```js
function permutator (inputArr) {
  const result = []

  function permute (arr, m = []) {
    if (arr.length) {
      arr.forEach((item, i) => {
        const restArr = [...arr.slice(0, i), ...arr.slice(i + 1)]
        permute(restArr, [...m, item])
      })
    } else {
      result.push(m)
    }
  }

  permute(inputArr)

  return result
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To solve this problem my idea was the following...

1- The total permutations of (n) are (n!).

2- Check combinations for small n (n <= 4).

3- Apply a recursive technique.

```
if(n == 1) // ['a']
    then permutation is (1) ['a']
if(n == 2) // ['a', 'b']
    then permutations are (2) ['a', 'b'] ['b', 'a']
if(n == 3) // ['a', 'b', 'c']
    then permutations are (6) ['a', 'b', 'c'] ['a', 'c', 'b'] ['b', 'a', 'c'] ['b', 'c', 'a'] ['c', 'a', 'b'] ['c', 'b', 'a']
```

So... There is a pattern in the permutations behavior.

Total permutations of and array instance are... all possible sub-permutations  removing from the original array each single char and concat the single char whit them relative sub-permutations. Ufff maybe the code can explain this better.

Bye!

```js
 function permutations(array) {
    let permutationList = [];

    if(array.length == 1) {
        return array;
    }

    for(let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        let arrayLength1 = [ array[i] ];
        let auxArray = Object.values(array);
        auxArray.splice(i, 1);

        let subPermutations = this.permutations(auxArray);

        for(let j = 0; j < subPermutations.length; j++) {
            let arrayMerge = arrayLength1.concat(subPermutations[j]);
            permutationList.push(arrayMerge);
        }
    }

    return permutationList;
}

let results4 = permutations(['a', 'b' ,'c', 'd']);
let results6 = permutations(['a', 'b' ,'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']);

console.log(results4.length);
console.log(results4);

console.log(results6.length);
console.log(results6);
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a [post](http://www.pixelstech.net/article/1316620955-Permutation-algorithm-with-JavaScript) to demonstrate how to permute an array in JavaScript. Here is the code which does this.

```
var count=0;
function permute(pre,cur){ 
    var len=cur.length;
    for(var i=0;i<len;i++){
        var p=clone(pre);
        var c=clone(cur);
        p.push(cur[i]);
        remove(c,cur[i]);
        if(len>1){
            permute(p,c);
        }else{
            print(p);
            count++;
        }
    }
}
function print(arr){
    var len=arr.length;
    for(var i=0;i<len;i++){
        document.write(arr[i]+" ");
    }
    document.write("<br />");
}
function remove(arr,item){
    if(contains(arr,item)){
        var len=arr.length;
        for(var i = len-1; i >= 0; i--){ // STEP 1
            if(arr[i] == item){             // STEP 2
                arr.splice(i,1);              // STEP 3
            }
        }
    }
}
function contains(arr,value){
    for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
        if(arr[i]==value){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
function clone(arr){
    var a=new Array();
    var len=arr.length;
    for(var i=0;i<len;i++){
        a.push(arr[i]);
    }
    return a;
}
```

Just call

> permute([], [1,2,3,4])

will work. For details on how this works, please refer to the explanation in that post.

Answer (score 0):

```
function nPr(xs, r) {
    if (!r) return [];
    return xs.reduce(function(memo, cur, i) {
        var others  = xs.slice(0,i).concat(xs.slice(i+1)),
            perms   = nPr(others, r-1),
            newElms = !perms.length ? [[cur]] :
                      perms.map(function(perm) { return [cur].concat(perm) });
        return memo.concat(newElms);
    }, []);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  let permutations = []

  permutate([], {
    color: ['red', 'green'],
    size: ['big', 'small', 'medium'],
    type: ['saison', 'oldtimer']
  })

  function permutate (currentVals, remainingAttrs) {
    remainingAttrs[Object.keys(remainingAttrs)[0]].forEach(attrVal => {
      let currentValsNew = currentVals.slice(0)
      currentValsNew.push(attrVal)

      if (Object.keys(remainingAttrs).length > 1) {
        let remainingAttrsNew = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(remainingAttrs))
        delete remainingAttrsNew[Object.keys(remainingAttrs)[0]]

        permutate(currentValsNew, remainingAttrsNew)
      } else {
        permutations.push(currentValsNew)
      }
    })
  }
```

Result:

```
[ 
  [ 'red', 'big', 'saison' ],
  [ 'red', 'big', 'oldtimer' ],
  [ 'red', 'small', 'saison' ],
  [ 'red', 'small', 'oldtimer' ],
  [ 'red', 'medium', 'saison' ],
  [ 'red', 'medium', 'oldtimer' ],
  [ 'green', 'big', 'saison' ],
  [ 'green', 'big', 'oldtimer' ],
  [ 'green', 'small', 'saison' ],
  [ 'green', 'small', 'oldtimer' ],
  [ 'green', 'medium', 'saison' ],
  [ 'green', 'medium', 'oldtimer' ] 
]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const removeItem = (arr, i) => {
  return arr.slice(0, i).concat(arr.slice(i+1));
}

const makePermutations = (strArr) => {
  const doPermutation = (strArr, pairArr) => {
    return strArr.reduce((result, permutItem, i) => {
      const currentPair = removeItem(pairArr, i);
      const tempResult = currentPair.map((item) => permutItem+item);
      return tempResult.length === 1 ? result.concat(tempResult) :
             result.concat(doPermutation(tempResult, currentPair));
    }, []);
  }
  return strArr.length === 1 ? strArr :
         doPermutation(strArr, strArr);
}


makePermutations(["a", "b", "c", "d"]);
//result: ["abcd", "abdc", "acbd", "acdb", "adbc", "adcb", "bacd", "badc", "bcad", "bcda", "bdac", "bdca", "cabd", "cadb", "cbad", "cbda", "cdab", "cdba", "dabc", "dacb", "dbac", "dbca", "dcab", "dcba"]
```

Answer (score 0):

I used a string instead of an array and it seems like my algorithm consumes very less time. I am posting my algorithm here, am I measuring the time correctly?

```
console.time('process');

var result = []

function swapper(toSwap){
    let start = toSwap[0]
    let end = toSwap.slice(1)
    return end + start
}


function perm(str){
    let i = str.length
    let filling = i - 1

    let buckets = i*filling
    let tmpSwap = ''
    for(let j=0; j<filling; j++){
        if(j===0){
            result.push(str)
        }else{
          if(j === 1){
              tmpSwap = swapper(str.slice(1))
              result.push(str[0]+ tmpSwap)
              if(j === filling-1 && result.length < buckets){
                  perm(swapper(str))
              }

          }else{
              tmpSwap = swapper(tmpSwap)
              result.push(str[0]+ tmpSwap)
              if(j === filling-1 && result.length < buckets){
                  perm(swapper(str))
              }
          }
        }
    }

    if(result.length = buckets){
      return result
    }else{
      return 'something went wrong'
    }

}





console.log(perm('abcdefghijk'))

console.timeEnd('process');
```

Answer (score 0):

I think perhaps the only difference in my solution below is that I stop the recursion one step before the null case. Hopefully the embedded comments are sufficient explanation.

```
function Permutations (A) // computes all possible ordered sequences of the entries in array A and returns them as an array of arrays
{
var perms = [];

for (var i = 0 ; i < A.length ; i++)
    {
    var rem = A.slice (0); // copy input array to retain remainder of elements after removing i'th element
    var el = rem.splice (i,1);
    if (A.length == 2) {perms.push ([el [0],rem [0]])} // recursion end case
    else 
        {
        var sub = Permutations (rem); // recursive call
        for (var s = 0 ; s < sub.length ; s++) // process recursive response, adding el to the start of each returned sequence
            {
            sub [s].splice (0,0,el [0]);
            perms.push (sub [s]);
            };
        };
    };

return perms ;

};// end of Permutations function
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll may like this one:

```
const permute1 = (arr: any[]): any[][] =>
  arr.reduce(
    (acc, curr) =>
      acc.length > 0
        ? acc
            .map((p) =>
              Array.from({ length: p.length + 1 }, (_, i) =>
                p.slice(0, i).concat(curr, p.slice(i))
              )
            )
            .flat()
        : [[curr]],
    []
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

here is a visualization for the recursive function =>  https://recursion.vercel.app/

```
 var permute = function (nums) {
  let answer = [];

  var permuter = function (arr, permutation = []) {
    if (arr.length === 0) {
      return answer.push(permutation);
    } else {
      for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        let currentArr = arr.slice();
        let next = currentArr.splice(i, 1);
        permuter(currentArr, permutation.concat(next)); ///we use concat because splice returns an array.
      }
    }
  };

  permuter(nums);

  return answer;
};
```

Answer (score -3):

Here's a very short solution, that only works for 1 or 2 long strings. It's a oneliner, and it's blazing fast, using ES6 and not depending on jQuery. Enjoy:

```
var p = l => l.length<2 ? [l] : l.length==2 ? [l[0]+l[1],l[1]+l[0]] : Function('throw Error("unimplemented")')();
```

Comment: You mean "string one or two chars long", because '1 or 2 long strings' means something else.

Answer (score -4):

```
function swap(array1, index1, index2) {
    var temp;
    temp = array1[index1];
    array1[index1] = array1[index2];
    array1[index2] = temp;
}

function permute(a, l, r) {
    var i;
    if (l == r) {
        console.log(a.join(''));
    } else {
        for (i = l; i <= r; i++) {
            swap(a, l, i);
            permute(a, l + 1, r);
            swap(a, l, i);
        }
    }
}


permute(["A","B","C", "D"],0,3);
```

// sample execution
//for more details refer this link

// http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/write-a-c-program-to-print-all-permutations-of-a-given-string/